# How do I change the colors of my graph in a MS Access Report?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, charts

I made a graph in MS Access Report feature but the colors are painfully old looking. Pastels and I need them to match the theme. I can't seem to find an option to change the colors anywhere for the bar graph. I tried searching but found no results. If anyone knows how to go from the 2000s to 2017 that would be great. Thanks for the help.

PS. I also am wondering how to place just one graph in the report for a categorical graph. If someone knows a link to where I can find more information on the report function of Access, please also comment that but the main issue is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

1. report in design view, double-click on the graph to go into edit mode
2. double-click on any bar to select that series and open Format Data Series dialog
3. set patterns and colors
4. click anywhere on the report to exit chart edit
5. Save

What do you mean by 'categorical' graph?

Have you Googled 'building Access reports'?